# Reference properties of null referenced object in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteriaquery

Here I have two `Entity` class.

```
@Table(name = "AC_ACCOUNT_MASTER")
public abstract class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "a_name")
    private String name;
}
```

And

```
@Table(name = "AC_VOUCHER_MASTER")
public class Voucher implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Double amt;

    @ManyToOne
    private Account drAc;

    @ManyToOne
    private Account crAc;

}
```

There are 10 rows in `AC_VOUCHER_MASTER` table, where 4 `drAc` data are `null` in `AC_VOUCHER_MASTER` table.

```
session.createQuery("select v.id, v.amount, v.drAc.id,  v.crAc.id  from Voucher v").list();
```

The above query returns me 10 result (although 4 `drAc` are `null`). But when I put name refernce (`v.drAc.name`), it returns only those rows (6 rows) that `drAc` is not `null`.

```
"select v.id, v.amount, v.drAc.id, v.drAc.name, v.crAc.id , v.crAc.name  from Voucher v"
```

What Should I do now ? Is there to use `coalesce()` or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join:

```
select v.id, v.amount, drAc.id, drAc.name, crAc.id , crAc.name 
from Voucher v
left join v.drAc drAc
left join v.crAc crAc
```